# Display warnings in the source code tree in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, code-inspection

Does anyone know if the warnings from *Code* -> *Inspect code* (for the whole project) can be displayed in the source code tree, similar to what is done in other IDEs?

I'd really like to have a feature like this - which makes these warnings stand out - because it reduces the risk that I commit code with warnings

Grateful for help!

Comment: Have you tried asking the PyCharm support forums?  The developers of PyCharm would be a better place to ask this question as they are the definitive developers and KNOW what their software can and can not do.